# What is the difference between Ctrl+R, Ctrl+D and Ctrl+R, D visual studio shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

The question itself is in the title. See screenshots.

When I'm using those **both** shortcuts, my Visual Studio 2010 does exactly the **same** action (debug tests). However, the shortcuts are assigned for different buttons.

What am I missing?

[image: Run button]
[image: Debug button]

**UPDATE:**

Here is my keyboard customizations in "Tools" - "Customize" - "Keyboard".

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, VS treats Ctrl+R,Ctrl+D and Ctrl+R,D as the same command.  There's ancient history behind this behavior, going all the way back to an old text editor named [Wordstar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordStar#Interface).  Which used control key chords like that.  Also adopted by Borland, a company that Microsoft was fiercely competitive with.  And by me, I still use it, got a weird left pinky to show for it.

You'll have to assign a different chord for the other command.

Comment: Seems dull that Microsoft released such a strange shortcut patterns. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that when using `CTRL+R, CTRL+D`, the test runner runs the tests with the debugger attached.

This means that you can set breakpoints in the tests and step through the code. It is very useful at times.

EDIT: I think I missed the fact that you probably know about the concept of debugging tests. As Fishermaen points out, the shortcuts might be messed up. Do you have Resharper or any other 3rd party tool that alters these settings perhaps?

Comment: Nope, I don't have. Let me check Customization.

Answer (score 0):

Check in "Tools" - "Customize" - "Keyboard" if the shortcuts are wired up correctly.

Comment: As you can see from the question update, everything seems correct.